# Display JavaScript array in vertical list

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have an array I have generated and I want to display it in html as a vertical list, preferably as each individual element.

I have done this:

```
var a = _.intersection(viewedUserLikedUsersArray, loggedInLikedUsersArray);
  for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++){
    displayListOfMatches.innerHTML = a[i];
  }
```

but obviously this way will replace the innerHTML with the last element in the array rather than stacking each one on top of each other

Comment: `displayListOfMatches.innerHTML += "<p>" + a[i] + "</p>";`

Comment: @ChrisG: Using `+=` with `innerHTML` is a bad idea.

Comment: `displayListOfMatches.innerHTML = a.join("<br>");` would be one way; no loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably get people saying to do this:

```
displayListOfMatches.innerHTML = "<p>" + a.join("</p><p>") + "</p>";
```

...which works ***but*** note that the content of the array entries will be parsed **as HTML**.

If that's not okay, you can either build an HTML string by replacing those characters via `map`:

```
displayListOfMatches.innerHTML = a.map(function(entry) {
    return "<p>" + entry.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;") + "</p>";
}).join("");
```

...or build the elements as you go, perhaps with `forEach`:

```
displayListOfMatches.innerHTML = ""; // You can leave this out if it's empty
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry));
    displayListOfMatches.appendChild(p);
});
```

Of course, in all cases, you can adjust it to use different elements/markup.

Comment: ok yeh think this makes sense. no idea why im getting a syntax error. i have just placed your code inside a function and now it is complaining about the last bracket...

Comment: @Theworm: That would be because I left off the `);` that should have been at the end of the second code block. :-) Sorry about that. It's there now.